# Render images progressively in a MFC based application

Tags: image, mfc, wic, progressive

Browser can render progressive images progressively.
And the images can only be progressively decoded if they were progressively encoded.

e.g., GIF or PNG images saved with the "interlaced" option, or JPEG images saved with the "progressive" option.

I want to render the progressive images in my MFC based application just like the browser does.

Windows Imaging Component provide IWICProgressiveLevelControl interface to decode image progressively.

But I can't find out any example to show how to stream and display image progressively at the same time using IWICProgressiveLevelControl.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good sample here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Imaging-Component-3af3cd49

Once you've used `IWICProgressiveLevelControl::SetCurrentLevel` to select the scan, the decoder will behave normally but only use the scans up to and including the one you selected.  So any call to `CopyPixels` or any `IWICBitmapSource` components in your chain will receive the fully decoded image at the selected scan level.

The trick, as demonstrated in the sample, is that you can't use `IWICProgressiveLevelControl::GetLevelCount` and select the max level immediately if you don't know the complete file is available.  As the documentation for the sample states,

> IWICProgressiveLevelControl allows you to control which progressive level of detail to use on the frame decode. It also allows you to query the total number of progressive levels in the file; however it is not recommended to use this method on JPEG images because the total count is not known until the entire image has been downloaded, defeating the purpose of progressive decode. Instead, this sample demonstrates the recommended practice of iteratively requesting increasing levels of detail until WIC returns WINCODEC_ERR_INVALIDPROGRESSIVELEVEL.